# Consulta al usar typed.js

Tags: javascript, html, consola

estoy intentando utilizar el framework `typed.js` y no logro hacerlo funcionar por esto

```
let typed = new Typed('#typed', {
    strings: [
                'My strings are: <i>strings</i> with', 
                'My strings are: <strong>HTML</strong>', 
                'My strings are: Chars &times; &copy;'
            ],
    typeSpeed: 0,
    backSpeed: 0,
    smartBackspace: true, // this is a default
    loop: true
});
```

En la consola recibo: **texto.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Typed is not defined
at texto.js:1:13**

Y mi html es solo para probar tengo esto

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="texto.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="text">
            <span id="typed"></span>
        </div>
        <script src="texto.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="typed.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! inverti el orden de los scripts... js es un lenguaje ordenado...

Comment: Invierte el orden de carga de tus scripts, primero el módulo y después `texto.js`.